# Overload resolution oddity

Tags: c#, .net, overload-resolution

Not sure if this is C# 4+ specific, but just noticed this.

Consider the following classes:

```
class Base
{
  protected void Foo(object bar, DayOfWeek day)
  {
  }
}

class Program : Base
{
  protected void Foo(object bar, object baz)
  {
  }

  void Bar(DayOfWeek day)
  {
    Foo(new { day }, day);
  }
}
```

The call to `Foo` in `Bar`, resolves to `Foo(object, object)`.

While changing it to:

```
class Base
{

}

class Program : Base
{
  protected void Foo(object bar, object baz)
  {
  }

  protected void Foo(object bar, DayOfWeek day)
  {
  }

  void Bar(DayOfWeek day)
  {
    Foo(new { day }, day);
  }
}
```

The call to `Foo` in `Bar`, resolves to `Foo(object, DayOfWeek)`.

My understanding is that it should always resolve as in the second example.

Is this a 'bug' or just my lack of understanding (or ignorance)?

**Update:**

Thanks for the answers. As I have found out, one can use `base.` to call the method in the base class. The problem comes back however when adding another derived class in the mix.

```
class Base
{
  protected void Foo(object bar, DayOfWeek day)
  {
  }
}

class Program : Base
{
  protected void Foo(object bar, object baz)
  {
  }

  void Bar(DayOfWeek day)
  {
    base.Foo(new { day }, day);
  }
}

class Derived : Program
{
  void Baz(DayOfWeek day)
  {
    base.Foo(new { day }, day);
  }
}
```

The `base.` call works in `Program`, but then resolves to `Foo(object, object)` in `Derived`.

How would one call `Foo(object,DayOfWeek)` from `Derived` then without having to create 'redundant' methods in `Program` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think for resolving method call it looks in its class first, since `DayOfWeek` can be passed as `object` type, it calls class own method, not the one from the base class.

In the second case, the method call resolves to a the more particular type parameter, therefore `Foo(object bar, DayOfWeek day)` gets called.

From MSDN - [Method resolution.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> methods in a **base class are not candidates if any method in a derived
>   class is applicable** (Section [7.5.5.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691356%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).
>
> - Given the set of applicable candidate function members, the best function member in that set is located.
> - If the set contains only one function member, then that function member is the best function member.
> - Otherwise, the best function member is the one function member that is better than all other function members **with respect to the given
>     argument list**, provided that each function member is compared to all
>     other function members using the rules in Section 7.4.2.2.
> - If there is not exactly one function member that is better than all other function members, then the function member invocation is
>     ambiguous and a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: I understand what it is seemingly trying to do, but that means the one with the 'object' parameter will veto all other overloads, and no way to call any specific overloads in the base class, which in turn makes inheritance very limited and error prone.

Comment: Thanks, found the 'law'. *methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable*. So this is normal... :*(

Comment: @lippie, I was about to quote that from the same link :)

Comment: As for my side issue. You can force calling the base class by adding `base.` to the call. At least calling them is still possible :)

Comment: @leppie or you can give the method a different name

Comment: @phoog: IIRC, that was what I was trying to prevent ;p The code structure was probably just not well-formed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to checkout Eric Lippert's blog - particularly this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/future-breaking-changes-part-three

Effectively though, the overload resolution algorithm searches the current class for an overload that can be called and only searches the base classes for alternatives when one isn't found in the current class.

In the first case the `Foo(object, object)` overload is applicable so no further searching is performed.

In the second case the `Foo(object DayOfWeek)` is better so it is used.

Read Eric's article for the full detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think the spec makes sense. The derived class programmer doesn't need to know the *unrelative* methods' implementation in base classes. Otherwise, an unlucky guy wrote a method with less compatiable than the one in its base classes(and this guy doesn't know the details of the base classes), the method in the base class is invoked then.

Comment: My issue lies more with how to actually call the (or a specific) base implementation (given the specced resolution). `base.` helps in some cases, but fails in further derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, the problem is related to the way overload resolution works. Just to add to that:

If `Base.Foo` were `public`, then you could do this to get to `Base.Foo` within `Derived` (assuming `Base.Foo` wasn't overriden):

```
((Base)this).Foo(new { day }, day);
```

Also, you have the option of overriding (if you can change `Base.Foo` to be `virtual`) or explicitly hiding `Base.Foo` within `Program` so when you call `base.Foo` within `Derived`, it still calls `Base.Foo` :

```
class Program : Base
{
  protected void Foo(object bar, object baz)
  {
  }

  protected new void Foo(object bar, DayOfWeek baz)
  {
    base.Foo(bar, baz);
  }

  void Bar(DayOfWeek day)
  {
    base.Foo(new { day }, day);
  }
}
```

---

As a side note:
*Usually*, derived classes provide overloads with *more specific* parameter types than their base class overloads (e.g. `Object.Equals(object)`, `String.Equals(string)`).

Even if there's a case for less (or equally) specific parameter types, they'd either *override* the base method (e.g. `Object.Equals(object)`, `String.Equals(object)` -> overrides `Object.Equals(object)`), or they just give it a different method name.

Comment: Interesting find on `public`. I wonder why it fails to work when it is `protected` even though I am in the derived class.

Comment: @leppie because the compiler doesn't have the smarts to know that the object referenced by `((Base)this)` is a `Derived`. As far as it knows, it could be referring to an instance of `Program2` that also derives from `Base`. If that was the case, you wouldn't be allowed to access `Program2.Foo` from within `Derived`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9zta243.aspx).