# How does this overload resolution make any sense?

Tags: c#, overloading

I just had a unit test fail for a strange reason involving `IDictionary<object, object>`.

`IDictionary<K,V>` has two `Remove` methods. One takes a `K`, the other takes a `KeyValuePair<K,V>`. Consider these two dictionaries that are very similar to each other, but don't quite act the same:

```
IDictionary<string, object> d1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
IDictionary<object, object> d2 = new Dictionary<object, object>();
d1.Add("1", 2);
d2.Add("1", 2);
Console.WriteLine(d1.Remove(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("1", 2)));
Console.WriteLine(d2.Remove(new KeyValuePair<object, object>("1", 2)));
```

The output is `True`, then `False`. Since `KeyValuePair<object,object>` is the exact type expected by `d2.Remove(KeyValuePair<object,object>)`, why does the compiler call `d2.Remove(object)` instead?

(**Post-mortem note:**

In the scenario that prompted my question, I wasn't using `IDictionary<object,object>` directly but rather through a generic parameter:

```
public class DictionaryTests<DictT> where DictT :
    IDictionary<object,object>, new()
```

since the problem is that `IDictionary` took priority over `ICollection` I decided to "even things out" by including `ICollection` in the list of constraints:

```
public class DictionaryTests<DictT> where DictT :
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<object, object>>, IDictionary<object,object>, new()
```

but this didn't change the compiler's mind... I wonder why not.)

Comment: IIRC, this is due to a match being found in the 'declaring type' and it does not proceed to the base type. I asked a similar question before. Looking for link. Edit: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12242346/15541 (your question is a duplicate)

Comment: Doh! Well it's not 100% duplicate since my question is about a generic interface right? `*`awaits the inevitable closure*

Comment: I think the same goes for for any type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide a solution to the problem (see comment too):

```
Console.WriteLine( 
   ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<object, object>) d2).
      Remove(new KeyValuePair<object, object>("1", 2)));
```

Comment: wired, didn't think about this.

Comment: @Tigran: Yeah, it caught me by surprise too (and not many things do!)

Comment: It seems like something that deserves a compiler warning, except maybe not, since it's by design and all. I wonder if there is some problem that the C# designers intended to solve with this rule.

Comment: @Qwertie: Resharper probably does this :) It can't be compiler warning, as the explicit code to make it unambiguous would be overkill. Best not to overload in the inheritance chain.

Comment: @Qwertie: Resharper does not warn about this.